# Does 'knockoff', meaning 'copy', come from the German word 'nach'?

Tags: etymology

Does the English expression 'knockoff', meaning 'copy', come from the German word 'nach'?  I am researching an old flute which is marked 'nach Myer', and it turns out that it signifies something like 'a copy of a Myer'.

Comment: *Nach* is German for "after, in the manner of". To *knock something off* means to do it quickly, in haste, and that meaning gets extended to "quick replica".

Comment: knockoff (n.) 
"cheap imitation," 1966, from the verbal phrase knock off "do hastily;" in reference to the casual way the things are made.http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Knockoff&searchmode=none

Comment: @Josh61 sounds like an answer if you expand on the etymology (1817?) of *knock off*.

Comment: There is no German word *nack*. The closest words in spelling to *nack* are the noun *der Nacke*, meaning 'neck' or 'nape', and the adjective *nackt*, meaning 'nude' or 'naked'. I have corrected the spelling in your question accordingly.

Comment: @ErikKowal - Just for correctness. It is der Nacken or das Genick.

Comment: @rogermue - Thanks. Sod's Law of Typos in Corrections is still going strong.

Answer (score 2):

Unlikely. Citations going back several hundred years in English relate the phrase to work being done hastily or shoddily - which, in turn, is the general property which is in turn ascribed to most counterfeit goods through the use of the term as a noun.

Comment: And from the other direction, *nach* means "after" as in "in the manner of". There's a big difference between something being honestly in the manner of a predecessor like a nach Meyer flute, and which as such be stamped "nach Meyer" by the maker and a knock-off.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any relation between the  English verb to knock which means to make a sound with the knuckles of your fist (knocking at/on the door)  and the German preposition nach.

I guess you take the pronunciation /nok/ and compare it with / nach/. But that leads you totally astray. In my view, knock and knuckle are related to a German word, Knochen (bone) and Knöchel  (little bones of hand or feet).

Of course, there is quite a semantic jump from to knock (sound) to "to knock sth off (to do sth hastily and not very accurately). And I think it would be interesting to study this semantic development more closely. One can only guess. I could  imagine that a badly written text where the letters are hardly readable was "knocked off", not by using the fingers but the paw or the knuckles of the hand. But there might be better associations.